# Why is Demon King not leaving purgatory?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Why are there no frontal battles between the Demon King and the Supreme Deity (the goddess)?

Is there a rule to prevent that?

Comment: I haven't read/watched the series but the question in the spoiler seems like a different question. if it is then it should be removed and asked separately

Comment: I thought it may be related to the fact that demon king didn't make its appearance on Earth. I'm going to delete it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a great war between the clans 3000 years before the current time in The Seven Deadly Sins. The two main clans on each side were the Demon and the Goddess clan. There indeed must have been battles between the Demon King and the Supreme Deity at that time however none of that is shown in the anime or the manga. At the end of the war, the Goddess clan basically ended up defeating the Demon Clan by sealing them away for good using the [Coffin of Eternal Darkness](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Coffin_of_Eternal_Darkness). The seal was eventually broken partially by Hendricksen freeing the Ten Commandments and many other demons but it was not enough to revive the Demon King himself.

So basically, Demon King cannot leave the [Purgatory](http://nanatsu-no-taizai.wikia.com/wiki/Purgatory). The Purgatory is a space between the living and the afterlife. It is similar to how Meliodas didn't move go to the afterlife and instead went to the Purgatory. So the Demon King isn't really dead but not much of a living being either. He is simply waiting for someone to revive him.

Comment: I'm really impressed by the fact that demon king can't break the seal. However, I found this: (spoiler alert) https://i.imgur.com/xdrRv6P.png interesting.

Comment: @ShadowXsc That's interesting. I guess I missed that. It does hint that he simply might not be able to stay in the world without somehow destroying. But I am fairly certain about the fact the fact why he's not leaving the purgatory.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because he can't break the seal. Unlike most of the other demons, he was never sealed because he never actively participated in the war. He was stuck in Purgatory.

The answer is that he is simply too powerful. Meliodas mentions:

> The Demon King's power is great. Which means I will most likely not be able to stay in this world, Britannia, anymore.

The Demon King would probably destroy Britannia by his sheer power if he stays there. That's why he uses Wandle to keep an eye on Meliodas, then when Wandle died, he uses Hawk.

Comment: Yeah. I pointed out meliodas' statement (see the comment of first answer). Why would he care if britannia is destroyed, he wants to win the war, so, with that much power why not go straight in for a win, or a death battle vs goddesses